# I can't solve this 2nd order non-homogeneous DE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, problem-solving

I'll make it brief.

I need to solve the equation:
$$
y'' + y = 5xe^{2x}
$$

which should yield the result:
$$
y = A\cos x + B\sin x + xe^{2x} - \frac{4}{5}e^{2x}
$$

I almost get the correct solution apart from the last negative term, and I have no idea where it comes from. I know that the C.F. has to be $A\cos x + B\sin x$, and I tried a P.I. of $y = \lambda x e^{kx}$ and when comparing coefficients after reinserting $y$ and $y''$, I am left with:
$$
e^{kx}(k^2\lambda x + 2k\lambda + \lambda x) = 5xe^{kx}
$$

As a result, I correctly acquired that $k = 2$, but I am left with:
$$
5 \lambda x + 4 \lambda = 5x
$$

which leads me to nonsense.

Can anyone care to help me and tell me where I went wrong? Much appreciated.

I have a feeling this is one of those situations where I'll slap my forehead once I realise what I did wrong.

Answer (score 1):

When your forcing function is a polynomial ($x$) times another function whose derivative keeps its form ($e^{2x}$), your guess for the particular solution should be that function times an arbitrary polynomial of the same degree (or higher, if the function appears in the homogeneous solution). In particular, note that even if some of the coefficients for the forcing function polynomial are 0 (like the $x^0$ term), the particular solution should still have an arbitrary coefficient. For your case, you should try $y_p(x)=(\lambda x+\gamma)e^{2x}$.

From there, you should be able to plug in and evaluate the derivatives to solve for $\lambda$ and $\gamma$.

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying, but I was taught that the particular integral (solution) cannot have a term that is also part of the complementary (homogenous) solution. According to the auxiliary equation, the complementary solution is complex $A\cos x + B\sin x$, so I figured simply using a structure akin to the forcing function should suffice as there is no clash. I once took a similar approach where the homogeneous solution was $(A+Bx)e^{kx}$ so therefore I took a particular solution of $\lambda x^2 e^{kx}$, which yielded the correct answer, I didn't need to insert the $x^0$ term.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand what your issue is, but in this problem neither $e^{2x}$ nor $xe^{2x}$ are in the homogenous solution. If $e^{2x}$ were in the homogenous solution, then I don't know if you would need the $e^{2x}$ in the particular solution, but I'd keep it anyways, and you get either a number or a tautology.

Comment: @DanielPodobinski If you have a homogenous solution with both $e^{2x}$ and $xe^{2x}$ terms, and a forcing function of $xe^{2x}$, then you should guess a particular solution of $(Ax^2+Bx+C)e^{2x}$. Maybe you get $A=0$, idk. The key is to have at least one term which is _not_ in the homogenous solution, and enough variables ($A,B,C$) to solve the equations ($x^2e^{2x},xe^{2x},e^{2x}$).

Comment: I'm confused as to why I should need to insert $(\lambda x + \mu)e^{2x}$ instead of simply $\lambda x e^{2x}$. I was taught that the particular integral (PI) that you choose should have the same structure as the forcing function (FF), so if we have an FF of $e^{2x}$, I simply start with a guess of $\lambda e^{kx}$, UNLESS it appears in the homogenous solution (HS), in which case we simply multiply our PI by x in order to avoid the conflict with the HS. I wasn't taught that I need to have an entire polynomial. If I was taught wrong, then I've unfortunately understood this incorrectly.

Comment: As I mentioned, I also once had a problem where the FF was something like $Ae^{kx}$, the HS was $(A+Bx)e^{kx}$ and so therefore I chose a PI which was $\lambda x^2e^{kx}$, to avoid the conflict with the HS, and this yielded the correct answer. If I've understood you correctly, then I should have instead chosen a PI of $(\lambda x^2 + \mu x + \nu)e^{kx}$, but I would simply find that $\mu$ and $\nu$ would be equal to zero, correct? If so, was I simply lucky with my guess, then?

Comment: @DanielPodobinski That sounds correct. The key thing that I think you're hung up on is that a forcing function of $xe^{kx}$ _is_ of the form $(\lambda x+\mu)e^{kx}$ with $(\lambda,\mu)=(1,0)$. The reason why it's that and not just $\lambda xe^{kx}$ is because the derivative of $\lambda xe^{kx}$ is of the form $(\lambda x+\mu)e^{kx}$ ie. not the same family, but the derivative of $(\lambda x+\mu)e^{kx}$ is still of the form $(\lambda x+\mu)e^{kx}$. This property of must-differentiate-to-the-same-family is necessary anytime you choose a forcing function

Comment: Thank you, that clears things up. Would you happen to know a good source for understanding solving 2nd order non-homogeneous DE's at a more fundamental level? Thanks in advance and thanks for the help so far. :)